# Show content from custom tables into wordpress standard rss feeds

Tags: wordpress, rss

I am interested in showing content from my custom wordpress tables which includes various fields into wordpress Standard RSS Feed.

I have so far managed to display custom post type into standard feeds, however, this doesn't do my job as the content I want to display resides in a different custom tables. Content I will be pulling is about title, url, short_description, date etc

Code I have so far is:

```
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');

function myfeed_request($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed']))
        $qv['post_type'] = array('ipc_project_update');
    return $qv;
}
```

Above code pulls content for post type 'ipc_project_update', however, I want to change it so it pulls content from my custom tables. Any help please on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I guess I answer my own question.

The way I have accomplished it is using by following the workflow as:

1. Create a custom template file for rss feed which contains all queries to pull your required content and rss code.
2. Then cope the following code inside your theme's `functions.php`

Code:

```
remove_all_actions( "do_feed_rss2" );

add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'ipc_project_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );

function ipc_project_feed_rss2( ) {
    if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/ipc_rss_feed_template.php'))
        load_template( TEMPLATEPATH . '/ipc_rss_feed_template.php');
    else
        die("RSS Feed not found..");
}
```

The code above will override your standard feed so it uses your new custom template file for RSS Feeds